# Find height of element containing text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a box with fixed width (800px) that is filled with contents from nicEdit.

I need to know the height of the contents that are put inside the box, if I count the number of rows it will not work with long texts or with images or different font sizes...

I need to find the height to set the box with an height that will not show scrollbars and will not be higher than the content.

```
<div style="width: 800px; overflow: hidden"><?= $contentbyuser; ?></div>
```

This "page" will be shown into an iFrame with a code like:

```
<iframe style="width: 800px;height:???px;" src="page.php"></iframe>
```

How can I find the height to set to the iframe with javascript and/or jQuery?

Comment: Do you have example code?

Comment: Post your code so we can see what you're talking about, please.

Comment: random content inside a box, make the box high enough to show all the content, what code do you need?

Comment: It would help to know what you mean by "box". Is it just a `div` element?

Comment: why is there a scrollbar to begin with?

Comment: We'd need the code that lets us know what "box" and "content" are.

Comment: if your box is a div, leave height as none. Height will be automatically set to the length of contents.

Comment: it will be shown in an iframe so I need to know the height..

Comment: Let the height of the div be automatic depending on the "content" it has, then you can update the height of the iframe to match the height of the div whenever you add new content to the div.

Comment: the iframe must have a fixed height same as the content put in it, I need to give an embed code to the users. Can someone tell me a solution to my question instead of find workaround?

Comment: I'm afraid we do not have sufficient information. Will you give us more code? Perhaps the code you are currently using? Maybe you even have a Fiddle for us that we could work with? Everything is better than pure guessing.

Comment: is just a concept mine, there isn't a real code, I just need to find the height of the DIV to set the height of the iframe which will shows the div.

Comment: The information you provided us with isn't helping at all. All we can do is keep on guessing. Tell us some more. Why don't the suggested solutions in these comments work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dummy element, insert the HTML into it, and then check its height.

```
//create dummy
var $dummy = $('<div />').css({ position : 'absolute', left : -9999, width : 800 }).html(randomTextandImages);

//add dummy to the DOM
$("body").append($dummy);

//get the height of the dummy
var theHeight = $dummy.height();

//at this point we can remove the dummy from the DOM
$dummy.remove();

//set the height of the iframe
$("iframe").height(theHeight);
```

Be aware that the dummy element should have the same CSS applied to it as your regular container, so that it will render the same. Font properties are particularly important (e.g. font-size, font-weight, line-height, etc.).

Setting the position to `absolute` and giving a large negative left property means this will occur off-screen, so the user won't see it happen.

Also, I can't remember if I'd had an issue with this in the past, but if you're getting a height of zero then the code that gets the height of the dummy should be put in a short timeout so the dummy can render before getting its height.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the div to be automatic based on the content. Then you can do this in your JavaScript:

```
$("div").html(randomTextandImages);
var height = $('div').height();        // Give this to whoever will be using the iframe
```